# SQL - Assign number to each row in DESC order of purchase quantities

Tags: sql-server

I have the below table structure and I need to assign a number to each customer, in a descending way, based on the total quantity purchased:

```
customerid  order_date  item    quantity    price

10330       2016-06-30  Skateboard  1       28.00
10101       2016-06-30  Raft        1       58.00
10298       2016-07-01  Skateboard  1       33.00
10101       2016-07-01  Snow Shoes  4       125.00
10299       2016-07-06  Parachute   1       1250.00
10339       2016-07-27  Umbrella    1       4.500
10449       2016-08-13  Bicycle     1       180.790
10439       2016-08-14  Ski Poles   2       25.500
```

What I have tried so far is the below query but it still does not to seem right:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY sum(quantity) DESC) FROM IMP_MyTablee
GROUP BY customerid, order_date, item, quantity, price
```

Can anyone tipe me off? Thanks

**Desired output**

I need to see the `CustomerID` once no matter how many records are and the total quantity purchased and also to be ranked:

```
customerid  order_date  item    quantity    price    rank

10330       2016-06-30  Skateboard  5       28.00      1
10101       2016-06-30  Raft        3       58.00      3
10298       2016-07-01  Skateboard  4       33.00      2
```

Comment: what would the expected results be? It's hard to tell if you want to rank each customer internally, or against other customers, or both....

Comment: If you want the rank per customer, why would you still want order details in the final result? That seems arbitrary. Do you want all of those with the customer rank repeated?

Comment: What is the logic behind that output? How come, say, customerId 10101 have 2016-06-30 as order_date when he made that total on 2 different dates? Different items and quantity too. Maybe just selecting arbitrary data?

Comment: Yes, no matter the order date.

Comment: if you can get the output that you want without the rank, then you make that query a subquery, and query it to make a rank - have you got to the first stage?

Comment: what happened to snow shoes for 10101? Why did you pick Raft or drop the snow shoes? This doesn't make sense

Comment: Sorry but I can't see any logic in your selection.

Comment: What the purpose of `GROUP BY` if you don't have any aggregation???

Comment: A customer id, an order date, and an item is collectively a purchase. I think you need to explain what you are actually trying to do. Have you included things in your Desired output that you don't need and thought didn't matter? (They do matter) Or do you need them, in which case these are Purchases or Orders, not Customers, and therefore is a different matter

Comment: Why does your result set include the item?  Customer 10330 didn't buy 5 skateboards *(in fact, that customer didn't buy 5 of anything...)*.  If you are trying to rank the customers, your results shouldn't have an item column, or an order date column...

Answer (score 1):

Try this. First group and then rank

```
with A as (
    select * from 
        ( values 
            (10330, '2016-06-30', 'Skateboard', 1, 28.00),
            (10101, '2016-06-30', 'Raft'      , 1, 58.00),
            (10298, '2016-07-01', 'Skateboard', 1, 33.00),
            (10101, '2016-07-01', 'Snow Shoes', 4, 125.00),
            (10299, '2016-07-06', 'Parachute' , 1, 1250.00),
            (10339, '2016-07-27', 'Umbrella'  , 1, 4.500),
            (10449, '2016-08-13', 'Bicycle'   , 1, 180.790),
            (10439, '2016-08-14', 'Ski Poles' , 2, 25.500)
        ) as T(customerid,  order_date,  item,   quantity,    price)
)
, B as (
    select 
        customerid,
        item,
        sum(quantity) as total,
        price
    from
        A
    group by
        customerid, item, price
)
select top(3) *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by total desc) from B order by total desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Your specifications call for a query like this:

```
SELECT customerid, 
    SUM(Quantity) As Qty
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (GROUP BY customerid ORDER BY Sum(Quantity) desc) As Rank
FROM IMP_MyTablee
GROUP BY customerid
```

If you need detail as well, you need to specify what detail you need - SUM(price * Quantity), or MIN(order_date), or whatever....